# Difference between Assembly and class library?

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen some definitions on StackOverflow that explains that Assembly is the smallest unit of deployment of a .net application. It can be a dll or an exe and A class library usually is a DLL or a packet of classes that you can "include"/"reference" to your solution and reuse. I'm confused by this two definitions. Is Assembly and class library are the same?

Comment: An assembly is a distributable file in .NET and it can be a DLL or an exe. So a class library (dll) is also called an assembly in .NET

Comment: All german shepards are dogs but not all dogs are german shepards. So, a class lib is a ( one kind of ) assembly. But an assembly could also be an executable (exe).

Comment: @Fildor isn't it the other way round: I can use an *.exe as class library, too, but I can't start a dll (well I can by loading it and executing some of the exported methods)...I guess the *.exe part is only to enable the os to start it, having conventions like a `Main` method etc.

Comment: @Rene--you can't use an exe as a class library--try adding a reference to your so-called exe class library to another exe project. Just because an exe project contains classes, it does not make it a "library" that can be reused elsewhere.

Comment: @Polyfun Yet, Rene has a point there. While you cannot reference the .exe binary as you would a .dll you can still load the .exe's assembly...

Comment: @RenéVogt Yeah, my analogy is not all too perfect, I guess.

Comment: @Polyfun I tried adding an exe as reference, works perfectly for me. I can access all the (public) types in it. An exe is not much more than a dll with a `Main` method.